# How to avoid logging intermediate process states in Org-mode?

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

In [Org-mode](http://orgmode.org/) a task can have one of several process states (e.g. *TODO*, *DONE*...). The process state list is [configurable](http://orgmode.org/manual/Workflow-states.html) and the user may either set a task state directly, or they may cycle over all states using the S-Left and S-Right key combinations.

What I find counter-intuitive, however, is the interaction between [state change tracking](http://orgmode.org/manual/Tracking-TODO-state-changes.html#Tracking-TODO-state-changes) and the use of the S-Left and S-Right keys. More specifically, when using those keys one may go over several states before settling on the one they need, especially if they type too fast and skip a desired state. Unfortunately, Org-mode will happily log *every single one* of those state changes, despite the fact that they happened within a few seconds and cannot correspond to what happened with an actual real-life task.

Is there a way to have Org-mode filter the generated log entries, so that those intermediate state changes are not inadvertently logged? E.g. a setting that would *merge* state changes when they happen in less than X seconds?

Comment: why not just call `org-todo`?

Comment: @abo-abo: `org-todo` brings up a new window that I find slightly distracting. I find S-Left / S-Right more convenient...

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/abo-abo/worf? Shortcut to change to TODO is `cwt`, to NEXT is `cwn` and so on. No extra window.

Answer (score 1):

To select a TODO state and bypass any logging associated with that, use:

```
(setq org-treat-S-cursor-todo-selection-as-state-change nil)
```

in your Emacs configuration file.

Comment: This disables logging for the S-keys altogether, which is not really what I am looking for. Still it could be a solution for some people, so +1...

Answer (score 0):

Call org-todo with a prefix argument using C-u followed by a number. This avoids the extra window.

From M-x describe-function RET org-todo RET:

> With C-u prefix arg, use completion to determine the new state. With
>   numeric prefix arg, switch to that state. With a double C-u prefix,
>   switch to the next set of TODO keywords (nextset). With a triple C-u
>   prefix, circumvent any state blocking. With a numeric prefix arg of 0,
>   inhibit note taking for the change.

So, using the example from the manual you linked, let's say you had the following workflow states defined:

```
(setq org-todo-keywords
      '((sequence "TODO" "FEEDBACK" "VERIFY" "|" "DONE" "DELEGATED")))
```

And you had the following in an org file:

```
* TODO Go Grocery Shopping
```

You could go immediate from TODO to DONE by typing C-u 4 C-c C-t. The result should look something like:

```
* DONE Go Grocery Shopping
  :LOGBOOK:
  - State "DONE"    from     "TODO"    [2014-10-30 Thu 09:20]
  :END:
```

Assuming you have the following in your init.el / .emacs file (which I highly recommend):

```
(setq org-log-into-drawer t)
```

Keep in mind if you have multiple workflow states defined (e.g. one for tasks, one for events, etc.), the prefix number goes in order of the keywords. Org-mode doesn't distinguish between different workflow sequences.

Comment: So you go from having to type `C-c C-t d` to `C-u 4 C-c C-t`. I really can't see this as more convenient...

Comment: You could always remap the keys to something more convenient. Why not map F1-F12 to your task states?

Comment: That's what I have done ATM, by binding `C-c d` to DONE. However, if I want to create more complex state sequences (which I do) it feels far more natural to me to cycle states, rather than select them directly...